# Forcing extension in SaveDialog

Tags: c#

Is there a straight-forward way of pulling the extension from the Filter so that an extension is always added (ala Word and Notepad).  Even with AddExtension = true, a filename with a period in it does not get the extension, e.g., my.file does not save as my.file.txt.

**Update**  The filter index looks like so:

```
Text (Tab delimited) (*.txt)|*.txt|Unicode text (*.txt)|*.txt|
CSV (Comma delimited) (*.csv)|*.csv|Rich Text Format (*.rtf)|*.rtf|
Web Page (*.htm;*.html)|*.htm;*.html
```

So indeed, there are some ambiguous extensions (though the first one is intended).  When FilterIndex is 1, for example, the intent is that the file has .txt at the end, regardless of what is there (except, of course, if it is already txt)

Comment: that depends on the filter - if it is a multi-filter that would be ambigous... please give more information...

Comment: you can always use http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/beth2052.aspx to check for an extension/add/change/remove extension etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check the filename returned for your extension.  If the last characters (say, 4 for a period plus 3-letter extension) do not match, append the extension to the given filename.

Comment: Do I have to regex my Filter to get the Filter extension?  Or is there a short cut?

Answer (score -1):

```
SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
saveFileDialog.Filter = "MY Project|*.mypi";
```

Comment: How does this answer the question? He's got the filter index set correctly already.

Comment: This doesnt answer the question please add further context to it.